# How number of thresholds is defined in sklearn roc_curve function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, roc

When I used sklearn function roc_curve on my data with logistic regression model:

```
roc_curve(y_test, predictions_test)
```

I got this result:

```
(array([0. , 0.1, 1. ]), array([0.   , 0.865, 1.   ]), array([2, 1, 0]))
In [137]:
```

I know that in third array there are thresholds and in first and second there are corresponding TPR and FPR. But I dint understand why there are three thresholds. How number of thresholds is defined in this function? For example when I use logistic regression, thresholds must be probabilities from sigmoid function, but here they are 2,1,0. Why so?

Comment: Actually, I realized ex-post that a specification of what your `predictions_test` is might help to improve the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you might see from the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7e1e6d09bcc2eaeba98f7e737aac2ac782f0e5f1/sklearn/metrics/_ranking.py#L765) (within the call to `_binary_clf_curve()`, in turn called by `roc_curve()` [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7e1e6d09bcc2eaeba98f7e737aac2ac782f0e5f1/sklearn/metrics/_ranking.py#L962)) the number of thresholds is actually defined by the number of distinct `predictions_test` (scores, in principle). From your output, however, I would suppose `predictions_test` might be the output of `.predict()` (perhaps of a multiclass classification problem? - in which case by the way you'll need to extend the ROC curve definition to deal with multiclass setting) rather than of `.predict_proba()` or `.decision_function()` as `roc_curve` requires.

Moreover, be aware that `roc_curve` also has a parameter `drop_intermediate` (default to True) which, in some cases, might drop suboptimal thresholds.

Eventually, I'd suggest the following posts:

- [Plotting the ROC curve for a multiclass problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70278059/plotting-the-roc-curve-for-a-multiclass-problem/70279497#70279497) for the ROC curve extension to a multiclass setting;
- [sklearn.metrics.roc_curve only shows 5 fprs, tprs, thresholds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69851350/sklearn-metrics-roc-curve-only-shows-5-fprs-tprs-thresholds/69853646#69853646) or [sklearn's roc_curve() function returns thresholds and fpr of different dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66277991/sklearns-roc-curve-function-returns-thresholds-and-fpr-of-different-dimension/66280301#66280301) for a better understanding of the implications of the parameter `drop_intermediate=True`.